# Django - __str__ method not working, says name is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-models, nameerror

I have the following model defined.

```
class Response(models.Model):

  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

  STATEMENT_CHOICES = (
    (-1, "Strongly Disagree"),
    (-0.5, "Somewhat Disagree"),
    (0, "Uncertain"),
    (0.5, "Somewhat Agree"),
    (1, "Strongly Agree"),
  )

  statement = models.DecimalField(
    max_digits=2,
    decimal_places=1,
    choices = STATEMENT_CHOICES
  )

  def __str__(self):
    return self.statement
```

when I run the django shell, I create a question `q` that says `you like pizza` and response `r` which is `1` for `strongly agree`. then when I run the `__str__` method on `r` I get an error saying `name 'statement' is not defined`.

Here is the exact console output...

```
>>> q
<Question: You like pizza.>
>>> r = Response(question=q, statement=1)
>>> r.question
<Question: You like pizza.>
>>> r.statement
1
>>> r
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/TN/Documents/Programming/Django/Practice/myve  /lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 572, in __repr__
    u = six.text_type(self)
  File "/Users/TN/Documents/Programming/Django/Practice/mysite/personalityQuiz/models.py", line 48, in __str__
    return self.statement
NameError: name 'statement' is not defined
```

Comment: Could there be something  going on with the formatting of your code in the file? Does it iffer in any way from the way you've written it here? I find it weird that you're getting a NameError, as you're accessing an attribute, I'd expect an AttributeError.

For example, did you write `return self,statement`, with a comma instead of a period?

Comment: Maybe you changed `models.py` after starting your interpreter? In that case, the stacktrace will show the code on the filesystem instead of the code loaded in the interpreter.

Comment: Yes, that must have been in Erik.  Thanks. of course - now I get another error "__str__ returned non-string (type int)" , do you know how I could return the text from the tuple instead of the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.get_statement_display()` to return the description of the choice. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) for more info.